# Rotation of "Array of Array" (Matrix)

Tags: arrays, matrix, rotation, pascal

So, I'm a beginner. I'm trying to make a program, which determines if two matrices, which the user puts in, have a corresponding transformation (rotation), from the first matrix to the second matrix.
The output would be like this (keep in mind that the brackets "[...]" are used to show the input of the user),

```
Please input the value of N : [3]
Matrix A
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
[7] [8] [9]
Matrix B
[7] [4] [1]
[8] [5] [2]
[9] [6] [3]
Matrix B is 90 degree rotated Matrix A
------------------------------------------
Please input the value of N : [3]
Matrix A
[1] [2] [3]
[4] [5] [6]
[7] [8] [9]
Matrix B
[9] [8] [7]
[6] [5] [4]
[3] [2] [1]
Matrix B is 180 degree rotated Matrix A
```

Assume the matrix rotates to the right. If Matrix B is the same as Matrix A, then the output would be a 0 degree rotated matrix.

Here is my  attempt in Pascal:

```
Program Matrix_Rotation;

Var

   TabA,TabB : Array [1..9] of Array [1..9] of integer;
   i,j,n,checker1,checker2,checker3,checker4 : integer;

Begin

      Write('Please input the value of N : '); Readln(n);
      If ((n > 0) and (n < 10)) then
      Begin
            Writeln('Matrix A');
            For i := 1 to n do
            Begin
                  For j := 1 to n do
                  Begin
                        Read(TabA[i][j]);
                  End;
                  Writeln;
            End;
            Writeln('Matrix B');
            For i := 1 to n do
            Begin
                  For j := 1 to n do
                  Begin
                        Read(TabB[i][j]);
                  End;
                  Writeln;
            End;
            checker1 := 0;
            checker2 := 0;
            checker3 := 0;
            checker4 := 0;
            For i := 1 to n do
            Begin
                  For j := 1 to n do
                  Begin
                        If TabA[i][j] = TabB[j][n+1-i] then
                        Begin
                              checker1 := checker1 + 1;
                        End else if TabA[i][j] = TabB[n+1-i][n+1-j] then
                        Begin
                              checker2 := checker2 + 1;
                        End else if TabA[i][j] = TabB[n+1-j][i] then
                        Begin
                              checker3 := checker3 + 1;
                        End else if TabA[i][j] = TabB[i][j] then
                        Begin
                              checker4 := checker4 + 1;
                        End else
                        Begin
                              checker1 := checker1;
                              checker2 := checker2;
                              checker3 := checker3;
                              checker4 := checker4;
                        End;
                  End;
            End;
            If checker1 = (n * n) then
            Begin
                  Writeln('Matrix B is 90 degree rotated matrix A');
            End else if checker2 = (n * n) then
            Begin
                  Writeln('Matrix B is 180 degree rotated matrix A');
            End else if checker3 = (n * n) then
            Begin
                  Writeln('Matrix B is 270 degree rotated matrix A');
            End else if checker4 = (n * n) then
            Begin
                  Writeln('Matrix B is 0 degree rotated matrix A');
            End else
            Begin
                  Writeln('Matrix B doesn't correspond with matrix A');
            End;
      End else
      Begin
            Writeln('The value of N must be between 1 and 9');
      End;

End.
```

I tried to input 4 as the value of N, and my Matrix A and Matrix B are like this:

```
Matrix A
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
Matrix B
4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
```

I didn't get the output wanted, which is "Matrix B is 180 rotated matrix A". Instead, I got the message, "Matrix A doesn't correspond with matrix B". The same case with 270 rotated matrix A.
I thought this was caused by not unique matrix elements. But if that were true, how should I change the codes so that it would work on matrix with several similar matrix elements? I'm stuck on this. Please make the codes *as simple as possible*.

Comment: Just a general suggestion, and following simple, common good programming principles: you should create subroutines to help you. Write a function or procedure that takes a matrix and produces a rotated matrix. You could give it an argument for "how much" you want to rotate (e.g., 90, 180, or 270), or you could have it just do 90 and you could call it multiple times to get the others. The other function or procedure you need is one that compares two matrices and determines if they're equal.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. I might have wanted to use functions or procedures. However, what I wanted to do is, if a user inputs two matrices, the program will show the user whether there is a correspondence in terms of matrix rotation or not. I thought this was hard to make a function/procedure of this, since it's two matrices. But I should be wrong. I'll try to use functions/procedures next time.

Comment: I know what you're trying to achieve and breaking it down with functions will make it simpler. Your question asked how you should change the code, so that's my recommendation. Another procedure that would be handy would be one that reads a matrix from the user. You'd call that one twice. No sense in repeating that code literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I didn't get the output wanted, which is "Matrix B is 180 rotated matrix A".   […]

In your code the control structure

```pascal
if X = 123 then
begin
    foo;
end
else if X = 456 then
begin
    bar;
end
else
begin
    boing;
end;
```

is equivalent to

```
case X of
    123:
    begin
        foo;
    456:
    begin
        bar;
    end;
    otherwise
    begin
        boing;
    end
end;
```

Like in a `case` structure, each branch (`foo`/`bar`/`boing`) is taken *alternatively*.
Your program is currently assuming that two matrices are *either* the same, rotated left/right, upside down, or not the same, but only *one* of which can be true.
With a `case` (or in your code `if … then else if … then else` structure) it is impossible to cover the case that *multiple* rotations apply.

I hope this is enough of a hint. Besides, please don’t do ”null assignments“ (`checker1 := checker1;`).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the big hint! That's exactly the problem when I tried to re-read my code again after a while now ever since I was a beginner at programming. Re-reading my code here it does look messy, but I'm surprised with my past self with the quite smart idea to use "checkers" for faster computing time, instead of trying to do all 3 possible rotations and comparing it (easier to read & implement, but slower). Anyway, sending my kudos to you!